# How to check if an matrix (array) has a column that it's the same than a row

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I've been learning Java for three months in a grade, and now I'm redoing some exercises that we did before, and I'm doing one that I could not do it before.
The wording would be this:
Write a program that starts a matrhix of NxN through scanner and tells if exists a row exactlly the same than some column, joined the indexs of rows and columns that are the same.
For example, if we have the next bidimensional array:

```
   0   1   2
0 [1] [2] [1]
1 [4] [8] [2]
2 [3] [5] [1]
```

The program would tell me than the row 0 it's the same than the column 2.
Sorry for my bad english, I'm spanish.
So this is the code that I did:

```
package Arrays;

public class Ejercicio16 {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int matrix[][];
            int i, j;
            int rows, columns;
            boolean same = false;

            //1.Ask inf of the matrix to the user.
            do{ 
                rows = Teclado.nextInt("Insert the number of rows of the matrix");
                columns = Teclado.nextInt("Insert the number of columns of the matrix");    
            }while(rows<=0 && columns<=0);

    /*Teclado = A java class that I use with methos like nextInt, nextByte, etc with their try catchs and so on.It would be a Scanner method*/


    matrix = new int[rows][columns];



    for (i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<columns; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = Teclado.nextInt("Insert a value for the cell of the row: "+ i + " column: " + j);
                        }
                    }

            //4. Show the matrix inserted by the user.
            for (i=0; i<rows; i++){
                for (j=0; j<columns; j++){
                    System.out.print( "[" + matrix[i][j] + "]" + " ");
                    }
                System.out.println();
            }

            checkEquality(matrix, rows, columns, same);




        }
        public static boolean comprobarIgualdad(int matriz[][], int filas, int columnas, boolean igual){
            int i, j;

            for (i=0; i<rows; i++){
                for (j=0; j<columns; j++){
                    if(matrix[i] == matrix[j])
                        same = true;
                    else
                        same = false;
                    }

            }
            return same;





        }

    }
```

Now, my problem is: I don't know how to make the method to go overthe matrix vertically and horizontally and check if they are the same. I've been thinking these days but I couldn't find the answer, so I thought asking here for some help. I would like to make this problem by myself, but I think I can't, so any help is well received. If you have any ask about my code, just let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the rows have the same length than cols you can try this.

```
private boolean checkRowsEquality(int[][] matrix, int row, int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
           if (matrix[row][i] != matrix[i][col])
               return false;
    }
    return true;
}


private boolean checkEquality(int[][] matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            if (checkEquality(matrix, i, j)) 
               return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I Hope it helps.I'm from Spain too. Suerte :D

Comment: This method will only check if all columns and rows are equal, but it should check for each row/column pair. Also `if(isValid) return true` is redundant, why not simply `break;` and `return isValid;`?

Comment: Are you sure? Chek the code please. In addition `break;` is a bad practice

Comment: Your code compares matrix[0][0] and matrix[0][0], matrix[0][1] and matrix[1][0], matrix[0][2] and matrix[2][0] (e.g., row = 0 and column = 0). Next it compares matrix[1][0] and matrix[0][1], matrix[1][1] and matrix[1][1], matrix[1][2] and matrix[2][1] and at last it compares matrix[2][0] and matrix[0][2], matrix[2][1] and matrix[1][2], matrix[2][2] and matrix[2][2]. In short it compares row 0 and column 0, row 1 and column 1 and row 2 and column 2 but not row 0 and column 1, 2, row 1 column 0, 2 and so on.

Comment: Ok sorry. My fault. I MissUnderstood. I,m going to change it now

Comment: Also `break` is not bad practice if your loop is as short as yours. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, running over 2-dimensional arrays is always done in a nested loop as you may know. You would have to call `checkEquality()` with every possible constellation (i.e., row 0 and column 0, row 0 and column 1, row 0 and column 2, row 1 and column 0, ...).

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        if (checkEquality(matrix, i, j)) // no need for same here in my opinion
           System.out.println("Row " + i + " and " + " column " + j + " are equal.");
    }
}
[...]
private static boolean checkEquality(int[][] matrix, int row, int column) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) { // only works if number of rows equal number of columns
        if (matrix[row][i] != matrix[i][column]) { // running through rows and columns
            // if a single value is not equal you can stop searching and return false
            return false;
       }
    }
    return true; // otherwise it is true
}
```